# Word for academic fields that are aligned with a political movement or position?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, phrase-requests, adjectives, noun-phrases

Is there a word or phrase for academic fields that are aligned with a political movement or position? For example:

- Feminist studies is aligned with feminism. African American studies is closely aligned with the civil rights movement. Sociology, on the other hand, is not in general aligned with a specific political movement, and so wouldn't be under this word.
- Political science generally isn't aligned with a specific political position, and so wouldn't be covered under this word. Libertarian studies, on the other hand, would be covered by this word, being aligned with libertarianism. Same goes for Marxism.

An example sentence would be "Academics from x fields recently had a conference discussing the complex interplay of their various political movements."

Note that it should mean that they are *aligned* with a particular movement, not simply studying it (although they would probably do both). The study of history of Nazism probably wouldn't be this unless it also promoted Nazism.

Also, what would academics from those fields be called? (Also, is there a word for fields *not* aligned with a political movement or position?)

Note: I mean that a certain field is fundamentally aligned with a given political alignment, not specific individuals or outside forces.

Comment: Are you looking for something like "*on the same wavelength*"?

Comment: @Josh61 Not quite. Scientists from the same field usually are *on the same wavelength* about whatever their field is about (disagreeing only about new nuances typically). This is about an academic field also having a political component

Comment: So you could say that some academic fields are ***politicised***:  *overly influenced by politics   ⇒ They dismissed the report as highly politicized and biased.,   ⇒ The data that's being used to fault American education is highly politicized.* http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/politicised

Comment: @Josh61 Yeah, that sounds about right (although preferably it would be specific to academic fields instead of a general word).

Comment: Also ***ideologised*** : with an ideological character or interpretation to; especially :  to change or interpret in relation to a sociopolitical ideology often seen as biased or limited. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ideologize

Comment: The politicization of science is the manipulation of science for political gain. It occurs when government, business, or advocacy groups use legal or economic pressure to influence the findings of scientific research or the way it is disseminated, reported or interpreted. ***The politicization of science may also negatively affect academic and scientific freedom.*** https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politicization_of_science

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom I think that would be ambiguous, depending on the opinions of the speaker.

Comment: @Josh61 I'm thinking more about fields that started out aligned with a political alignment. Libertarian studies aren't libertarian because of outside influence.

Comment: Would "sympathetic" go far enough, as in Nazi sympathizers?  Or "collaborative", as in Nazi collaborators?

Answer (score 2):

For fields/disciplines where you feel that the “alignment” equates to “biased sympathy for” (as opposed to simple “neutral concentration/focus on”) political positions/movements, you could consider using”[agenda-driven](https://books.google.com/books?id=8KqFCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=%22agenda-driven%22+academic+fields&source=bl&ots=AkA_qnAW7m&sig=friKCGsx3j4xSyCmc29mGEUAEOQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9_-3mgKrLAhUMWh4KHZMxDB0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22agenda-driven%22%20academic%20fields&f=false)" and conversely perhaps “[agenda-neutral](https://books.google.com/books?id=FsqRAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=%22agenda-neutral%22+academic+fields&source=bl&ots=o1HaBu0L39&sig=O35aBn74eoc1Qe9fiUILPLk6Ncg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji75Lag6rLAhVHHR4KHZuSA_cQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22agenda-neutral%22%20academic%20fields&f=false)" for those that either have no alignment or that have not [yet] let their alignment/s become “biased sympathy for.”

(examples from ‘Animal Law and Welfare - International Perspectives’, edited by Deborah Cao, Steven White and ‘E-Research: Transformation in Scholarly Practice’ edited by Nicholas W. Jankowski, both via ‘Google Books’, respectively)

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***politically oriented***

> political orientation - an orientation that characterizes the thinking of a group or nation.
>
> [WordNet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/political+orientation)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "axiological positioning"? This connetcs to the social relations between the people and attitudes they have.